# Java FX TextArea Alignment

Tags: java, textarea, javafx, javafx-2

I want to display a text inside a Java FX Text area.

My code is:

```
TextArea txt = new TextArea();
txt.setEditable(false);
txt.setStyle("-fx-font-alignment: center");
txt.setText(text);
```

But I'm not able to set a text alignment (inside the `TextArea`)

I tried this:

```
txt.setStyle("-fx-font-alignment: center");
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 7):

Apply the style to the text child:

```
.text-area *.text {
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

Comment: Weird is when i load this as an external css in Scene Builder 17.0.0 and apply .text-area class to TextArea, Scene Builder does not recognize that some css was changed in css inspector.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution for centering horizontally the content of textarea only using CSS.

i have used a class in css:

```
.centeredTextArea .scroll-pane .content .text {
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

and after i have added

```
styleClass="centeredTextArea"
```

to my textArea control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scene Builder instead for making the UI, it is super easy.
There you can easily use "Java fx text area" and everything. 
all you have to do is to import the jfoenix library and you are ready,and that too without coding.

Comment: Though this tool is useful for developers, it does not constitute a real answer to their question, please leave this sort of discussion as a comment instead next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try setStyle(-fx-padding: 0 10 0 10).

so in this case, 0 - top
10 - right
0 - bottom
10 - left padding.

You can replace 10 with your required value. It simply fits your text in the text box with a padding/space of 10. Had a similar problem. This thing worked for me.

Answer (score -5):

I don't know why you want to use a textArea, but if you just want to display some text you should use a TextField.

Or else to display text use:

```
Text text = new Text("text");
```

But i don't know what exactly it is that you want to do.